# 平均値を求める方法

Tags: python

下記のデータの各要素を参照して平均値を求める方法と、オブジェクトとして平均を求める方法を教えてください。

```
import numpy as np
x=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11])
print('x[0]=',x[0],'x[10]=',x[10])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11])

# 要素を集計して個数で割って平均を出す
sum = 0
for num in x:
    sum += num
print(sum / len(x))

# numpy の配列オブジェクトとして average メソッドを使う
print(np.average(x))
```